# What is difference between const and non const key?

Tags: c++, key, language-lawyer, key-value, stdmap

What is the difference between the following two lines?

```
map<int, float> map_data;
map<const int, float> map_data;
```

Comment: Question is famillar with, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307321/does-it-make-sense-to-make-stdmap-key-const

Answer (score 72, accepted):

- `int` and `const int` are two distinct types.
- `std::map<int, float>` and `std::map<const int, float>` are, similarly, different types.

The difference between `std::map<const int, float>` and `std::map<int, float>` is, to a degree, analogous to the difference between, say, `std::map<int, float>` and `std::map<std::string, float>`; **you get a fresh map type for each.**

In the non-`const` case, the internal key type *is* still non-`const` `int`:

```
std::map<const int, float>::key_type       => const int
std::map<int, float>::key_type             => int
```

However, map keys are *semantically* immutable, and all map operations that allow direct access to keys (for example, dereferencing iterators, which yields `value_type`) does `const`ify the `key_type`:

```
std::map<const int, float>::value_type => std::pair<const int, float>
std::map<int, float>::value_type       => std::pair<const int, float>
```

So the difference *may* be largely invisible to you in every way that matters, if your implementation allows it.

That's not always the case, though: the standard officially *requires* your key type to be copyable and moveable, and [some implementations re-use map nodes](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-July/015926.html); under those implementations, attempting to use a `const` key simply won't work.

Comment: `So the difference is largely invisible to you in every way that matters.` -- unless you use a stdlib that copies / moves Keys (like libc++), in which case the const version just breaks. See http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2011-July/015926.html for a related discussion.

Comment: @mitchnull Yep, good spot. ([btw](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262463/quoted-text-inline-with-the-rest-using-code-tags-is-bad-why/262475#comment52723_262463)!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "the standard officially requires your key type to be copyable and moveable". About being moveable, I cannot find that on the C++ standard copy I have, could you please provide reference or section number?

Comment: This is an excellent answer, finally it clarified the whole `const`-ness issue I had with maps. C++14 introduced the [transparent comparators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators) which add a bit of complexity just to keep us sharp :)

Comment: Ah, thank you for confirming that keys are not allowed to be const. I wanted my keys to be immutable and it drove me nuts -_-

Comment: @NoelWidmer: They will already be immutable to users of your map type, so even if making the keys `const` were okay you wouldn't need it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ***So the difference may be largely invisible to you in every way that matters, if your implementation allows it.*** Could you please explain that in simpler words? Do you mean some implementation allows non-const keys other than const keys?

Comment: I am currently having an issue where class A has a map<A, A>. I need to call a member function on the key and value recursively to go through this nested map structure. The class has a mutex that must be locked for the keys and values, but the key is const requiring const member function and locking the mutex requires non-const member function. The only good way I can think of is a const_cast. But I guess the key is not actually const, it is just exposed as const. So it should be fine to const_cast as long as I do not make the key actually const in map definition and wont edit the key - I hope

Answer (score 37):

The [key](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is already `const`, so it is redundant to write `const` in this case. Once an element is entered, its `key` cannot be changed.

---

### **Edit**:

As mentioned in the comments, there **is** difference between the two lines. For example, if you write a function that accepts `map<const int, int>`, you can't pass to it `map<int, int>` since they're *different types*.

But note that although they are different types, they behave the same since the key in a map is a `const` anyway...

So in conclusion.. The only difference is that they are two different types, you shouldn't care about anything else.

Comment: This is not (completely) correct. The interface of `std::map` exposes the key type as `const`, but that doesn't mean that the two template instantiations are the same as this answer might imply. `std::map<const int, float>` and `std::map<int, float>` are [different types](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d5261dd32220b034acffc54933351fac-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Comment: @jrok is correct, whereas this answer is not. The `key_type` is in fact still `int` in the former case.

Comment: I edit my answer, I hope it's better now. Thanks for your comments and correction.

Comment: @Maroun: Almost, but the key is _not_ `const` (i.e.  `geordi << TYPE<std::map<int, float>::key_type>; # int`). However, it is semantically immutable and all operations that directly access keys (for example, dereferencing an iterator) give you a `const`-ified version of the key value (i.e. `geordi << TYPE<std::map<int, float>::value_type>; # std::pair<int const, float>`).

Comment: @johnmac2332: Let this be a lesson that fast != perfect, and upvotes != correct.

Comment: @johnmac2332 Fast and Quick answers should highly appreciated. This is one of the quality Stackoverflow better than other webs. OP can further query in comment section. if he say thanks means probably he got the answer.

Comment: No one is perfect, we all do mistakes and learn from each other. We're here to learn and help :)

Comment: @Grijesh: Unfortunately the OP may _think_ he got the answer, because it appeared plausible, but was in fact misled and will go on to spread the misinformation. Speed/haste is absolutely _not_ a substitute for correctness. Why is everyone in such a hurry!?

Comment: @Maroun: Speak for yourself - I'm here for the rep and glory! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok, yes! I agree with you. Btw you posted a nice answer. And yes one should take time to post and to **accept** an answer. I myself most of time try to explain from fundamental and post long answers (but of-course delayed & low-voted posts). anyways,  I congrats Maroun for his 10K RP. Maroun posted many good answers and I found him a valuable contributor.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, likewise. This factual error is out of character!

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that the second variant will set the key type for the map as `const int`. From the "modifiability" point of view this is redundant, since the map already stores its keys as `const` objects.

However, this can also lead to unexpected and non-obvious differences in the behavior of these two maps. In C++ a template specialization written for type `T` is different from specialization written for type `const T`. That means the above two versions of the map might end up using different specializations of various "satellite" templates that depend on the key type. One example is the key comparator predicate. The first one will use `std::less<int>` while the second one will use `std::less<const int>`. By exploiting this difference you can easily make these maps to sort their elements in different order.

Issues like that are more obvious with the new C++11 containers like `std::unordered_map`. `std::unordered_map<const int, int>` will not even compile, since it will attempt to use a `std::hash<const int>` specialization for hashing the keys. Such specialization does not exist in the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

`const` can't be altered once set. And yes as per docs & other answer you should remember that `key` is `const` already.

Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/
Link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: Sorry i was supposed to write - can't. 
Mods have made edit - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While the behaviour of your application will typically be the same, it makes a difference to some compilers you might use. The more specific example of what brought me to this page in the first place:

Explicitly specifying a map as `map<const key, value>` builds successfully with the gnu toolkit;

However it crashes a Studio12 Solaris x86 build.

---

`map<key, value>` builds successfully on both. Behaviour of the application is unchanged.

Comment: "Crashes" in what way?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was complaining about `std::map::insert` having multiple declarations.

Comment: Yes, as I stated above: it makes a difference to the compiler.

Comment: Typically when we say "crash" we refer to unexpected and ungraceful runtime termination of a process. Compiler crashes are rare but do happen (particularly with new language features), and are very serious in nature (as build results go).

Comment: It _crashes_ my _build_, not _application_. Am I misusing the terminology?

Comment: In my opinion, I'm afraid so. :) I'd say it _breaks_ your build, but to "crash" seems quite specific and not what is going on here. YMMV, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Const keys can be helpful if the keys are pointers. Using const keys won't let you modify the pointed object when accessing the keys, consider this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

int glob = 10;

int main() {
    std::map<const int*, std::string> constKeyMap { { &glob, "foo"} };
    std::map<int*, std::string> keyMap { { &glob, "bar" } };

    for(const auto& kv : keyMap) { *(kv.first) = 20; }; // glob = 20
    for(const auto& kv : constKeyMap) { *(kv.first) = 20; }; // COMPILE ERROR

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the `key_type` is `const int*`, the pointer itself it not const, but the pointed `int` is const.

Answer (score -1):

const refers to a constant, that, once defined, can't be altered then... non const key is subjected to change... or cant even change, it's just that "no change" is guaranteed in const (once defined), and "change" may or may not occur in non const stuff.