# error: passing ‘const Cell’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Cell::printcell()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I was implementing Conway's Game of Life without using array,only storing the co-ordinates of living cells.

```
class Cell{
public:
int x;
int y;
Cell(int paramx,int paramy);
void printcell();
};
Cell::Cell(int paramx,int paramy)
{
x=paramx;
y=paramy;
}
void Cell::printcell()
{
cout<<x<<","<<y<<endl;
}
```

This piece of code gives me the error.

```
for(i=livingcells.begin();i!=livingcells.end();i++)
{
    cout<<i->second<<"--";
    (*i).first.printcell();
}
```

Error:

```
gameoflife.h++: In member function ‘void GoFBoard::printboard()’:
gameoflife.h++:44:24: error: passing ‘const Cell’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Cell::printcell()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
(*i).first.printcell();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: yes. How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: make `printcell()` a `const` function, i.e. `void Cell::printcell() const {...}`

Comment: still same. @vsoftco

Comment: @n.m. Better duplicate: [What is difference between const and non const key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638154/what-is-difference-between-const-and-non-const-key) The issue lies within the missing information in the question.

Comment: Should i write the whole code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error as you are calling printcell on const object. Use this to get over this error:-

```
void printcell() const;
```