# Why is a re-constructed map type different from the original one?

Tags: c++, types

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    typedef std::map<int,float> testmap;
    typedef std::map<int,float> testmap2;
    typedef std::map<typename testmap::value_type::first_type, typename testmap::value_type::second_type> rebuiltMap;
    std::cout << "map samenes: " << std::is_same<testmap, rebuiltMap>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "map samenes: " << std::is_same<testmap, testmap2>::value << "\n";
    std::cout << "original map type name " << typeid(testmap).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "same     map type name " << typeid(testmap2).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "rebuilt  map type name " << typeid(rebuiltMap).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "original map valuetype " << typeid(testmap::value_type).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "rebuilt  map valuetype " << typeid(rebuiltMap::value_type).name() << "\n";
}
```

This produces the following output:

> ```
> map samenes: 0
> map samenes: 1
> original map type name St3mapIifSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKifEEE
> same     map type name St3mapIifSt4lessIiESaISt4pairIKifEEE
> rebuilt  map type name St3mapIKifSt4lessIS0_ESaISt4pairIS0_fEEE
> original map valuetype St4pairIKifE
> rebuilt  map valuetype St4pairIKifE
> ```

Why is the "rebuilt" map type different from the simple map type, although both have the same value_type?
Background: i want to test if a container containing pairs is a map or not with a construct like

```
std::is_same<std::map<typename Container::value_type::first_type,
                      typename Container::value_type::second_type>,
             Container>::value
```

Comment: Demangled type names: `std::map<int, float, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, float> > >` and `std::map<int const, float, std::less<int const>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, float> > >`

Answer (score 5):

`testmap::value_type::first_type` is `const int` rather than `int`.

You could use `testmap::key_type` instead to get the correct type. Based on the pair type, it is not possible to distinguish const and non-const key type. That said, a const key would not satisfy the requirements of `std::map`, so you could simply assume that it is non-const and remove const from `testmap::value_type::first_type`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `std::map::value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`, not `std::pair<Key, Value>`.  The reason for that is you are never allowed to modify the key of a pair that is in the map.

To get the rebuilt map to be the same using `value_type::first_type` you need to remove that `const` using [`std::remove_const_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) like

```
typedef std::map<std::remove_const_t<typename testmap::value_type::first_type>, typename testmap::value_type::second_type> rebuiltMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this:

```
std::map<typename testmap::value_type::first_type, typename testmap::value_type::second_type>
```

… is not quite right, because a `const` is automatically added to the key for use in `value_type`, and [this results in a distinct type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639764/560648).

That's what GCC's mangled name is telling you:

```
St3mapIKifSt4lessIS0_ESaISt4pairIS0_fEEE
//     ^ const
```

---

My recommendation is to use the convenient type aliases provided by map:

```
std::map<typename testmap::key_type, typename testmap::mapped_type>
```

… or, for a complete solution:

```
std::map<
   typename testmap::key_type,
   typename testmap::mapped_type,
   typename testmap::key_compare,
   typename testmap::allocator_type
>
```

This is, after all, what the aliases are there for.

---

Or just use `testmap`!

Comment: Thanks, these answers solved my Problem. The key_type and mapped_type don't help in my case, because if the container is e.g. a std::list<std::pair<t1,t2>> they don't exist and the test would fail.

Comment: @Dr.JürgenHannappel But that's a good thing! I'd actually suggest you just check for the presence of `mapped_type` to find out whether your container is associative, rather than the "rebuilding" trick you're doing now. Your way has too many edge cases and compromises. You cannot get back, reliably, the information "this `value_type` belongs to a map". So instead architect your template code to be based on traits and properties of types.