# Difference between const map and map of const elements

Tags: c++

Is there a difference between these maps? When should each of them be used?

```
const map<string, vector<unsigned char>> map1;
const map<const string, const vector<unsigned char>> map2;
const map<const string, const vector<const unsigned char>> map3;
map<const string, const vector<unsigned char>> map4;
map<const string, const vector<const unsigned char>> map5;
```

Comment: Since [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is ordered the key is constant anyway, you don't have to specify it.

Comment: You can add/delete stuff from a map of const things?

Comment: vectors with a `const` type aren't really useful ([and not legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954906/does-c11-allow-vectorconst-t)). I'm not sure about maps though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a `const` container means the container is immutable. You can't change it.

Having a non-`const` container means the container is mutable. You *can* change it.

Changing a map means: adding to it, modifying the things it contains (if they are, themselves, mutable), removing from it.

By the way, [putting `const` on a map key is largely pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17639764/560648).

I'm not going to enumerate "when should each be used"; you use the right tool for the job, and there are a near-infinite number of possible jobs.